# java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

Maven3

Richfaces3.3

EJB3

Seam2

Hibernate

JSF1.2

JBoss6

I checked into scanning-deployers-jboss-beans.xml and there is a section:

"

java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

"

Have you any idea? Thank you

```
17:52:49,128 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/ 
17:52:49,222 WARN  [InterceptorInfoRepository] EJBTHREE-1852: InterceptorInfoRepository is deprecated
17:52:49,628 WARN  [InterceptorInfoRepository] EJBTHREE-1852: InterceptorInfoRepository is deprecated
17:52:49,643 WARN  [InterceptorInfoRepository] EJBTHREE-1852: InterceptorInfoRepository is deprecated
17:52:50,486 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///D:/dev/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/openmind-ear.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying openmind-ejb.jar: Exception while processing container metadata for EJB: ReportExcelRequestListBean in unit: openmind-ejb.jar
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:194) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:60) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception while processing container metadata for EJB: ReportExcelRequestListBean in unit: openmind-ejb.jar
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:561) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:177) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:42) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:35) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:86) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:122) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31) [:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.getGenericType(FieldRepository.java:67) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType(Field.java:223) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.toGenericString(Field.java:301) [:1.6.0_18]
    at org.jboss.injection.InjectionUtil.processFieldAnnotations(InjectionUtil.java:157) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.injection.InjectionUtil.processAnnotations(InjectionUtil.java:197) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.processMetadata(EJBContainer.java:781) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.processEJBContainerMetadata(Ejb3Deployment.java:471) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:553) [:1.7.21]
    ... 50 more

17:52:50,612 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
17:52:50,628 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.SendMailQueue
17:52:50,628 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
17:52:50,659 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.GenerateAndCheckOfferQueue
17:52:50,690 INFO  [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers
17:52:50,768 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/dev/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/openmind-ear.ear" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]

17:52:50,784 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
17:52:50,800 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
```

ReportExcelRequestList:

```
package de.openmind.weblogic.request;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Remove;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Destroy;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

import de.openmind.dao.request.ViewRequestDao;
import de.openmind.model.request.ViewRequest;
import de.openmind.utils.noentities.CountRequest;
import de.openmind.weblogic.status.OfferStatusList;
import de.openmind.weblogic.status.RequestStatusList;

@Stateful
@Name("reportExcelRequestList")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
public class ReportExcelRequestListBean implements ReportExcelRequestList {

    @Logger
    private Log log;

    @In(create = true)
    private RequestStatusList requestStatusList;

    @In(create = true)
    private OfferStatusList offerStatusList;

    @In(create = true)
    private FilterRequest filterRequest;

    @EJB
    private ViewRequestDao viewRequestDao;

    private DataModel<ViewRequest> normalisedRequestList = null;

    @Override
    public void setNormalisedRequestList(DataModel<ViewRequest> normalisedRequestList) {
        this.normalisedRequestList = normalisedRequestList;
    }

    @Override
    public DataModel<ViewRequest> getNormalisedRequestList() {
        log.debug("getNormalisedRequestList: starting...");
        if(normalisedRequestList == null) {
            normalisedRequestList = new ListDataModel<ViewRequest>();
            Collection<ViewRequest> requestList = viewRequestDao.findList(filterRequest.getSearchFilter(), requestStatusList.getStatusEnum(), offerStatusList.getOfferStatusList(), getCount().intValue(), 0);
            normalisedRequestList.setWrappedData(requestList);
            log.debug("getNormalisedRequestList: Set the data into normalisedRequestList.");
        }
        return normalisedRequestList;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getCount() {
        CountRequest countAllRequest = viewRequestDao.getListSize(
            filterRequest.getSearchFilter(), requestStatusList.getStatusEnum(), offerStatusList.getOfferStatusList());

        log.debug(String.format("getCount: size of count=%s", countAllRequest.getCountAllRequest()));
        return countAllRequest.getCountAllRequest();
    }

    @Override
    @Destroy
    @Remove
    public void destroy() {
        log.debug("destroy bean classname=" + this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```